# Is it possible to change/add the icon of an app without submitting a new binary?

Tags: applications, icon, app-store-connect

I had created a build with a friend's Mac, which I no longer have access to. Now, the last hurdle I have to overcome before my app is released is to create a unique app icon, but I'm not sure if you can do this without a Mac to create a new binary. Is it possible to do this from App Store Connect alone?

Comment: So...do you have your answer or are you still looking for one?   As currently written, it appears to be more of a rant.

Comment: @Allan it's more or less a rant, yeah. I'll delete it unless you think it has some future value to other users.

Comment: I appears to have value...I'd leave it up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do this without resubmitting the app.

However, you do not actually need to rebuild the app using Xcode, as you otherwise indicate. If you look at the application bundle, you find the icons are usually stored in Contents/Resources/.icns. You can edit that file to change the icon. There's no need to rebuild the actual app executable.

If you're working with a signed app, you'll need to run the `codesign` program to resign the app.

Comment: Is there a way to extract the app bundle from App Store Connect so that I can add the app icon?

Comment: Not really no, you need the zip file you've uploaded originally...

Comment: i see, how do you release a new build from App Store Connect/without Xcode? thanks for your time btw, i really do appreciate you helping out a newbie like me!

Comment: You could use Transporter for example. Or a tool like AppUploader.net if you’re running Windows or Linux. There’s also command line clients available.